# Calculate Interior angles of irregular polygon with side measurement as $900, 1165, 1093$ and $1457$

Tags: geometry, angle, polygons, quadrilateral

I have the measurements of the four sides of an irregular polygon and I need to find out the size of each interior angle.

[image]

I know the sum of the angles is $360^\circ$ but because it's not a regular polygon I don't know how to calculate each angle. The measurements of sides are $900, 1165, 1093$ and $1457$.

Comment: Also if your polygon is convex you need some other information to fix all the angles.

Comment: I cannot see the image. But in general, given just the sides of a quadrilateral, we cannot determine the angles. For if you imagine hinges at the corners, it is clear that the figure is not  rigid.  Even if the sides are equal, we have infinitely many possible angle combinations, for we can pull a square into any rhombus shape without changing the sides.

Comment: Is your polygon circumscribed or of maximal area ? If so, then the sum of opposite angles is $180^\circ.$

Comment: The 4 side lengths do not determine a unique quadrilateral.  If you made a model out of cardboard and tape, you would see that the joints have a lot of flexibility to them.